# describe triple integral algebraically and drawing

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Describe the iterated integral $\int_0^1\int_0^{1-(y-1)^2}\int_0^{2-x}f(x,y,z)dzdxdy$ both by algebraically and drawing.

That triple integral looks crazy for me.. how can I define a set that describe it.
The only thing i know about the set is $x,y,z \ge 0$...

Comment: Sorry but what do u mean by ...algebraically...``? Are u looking for a nice plotting illustrating the integrals???

Answer (score 2):

The region is a solid one which is bounded by the plane $z=0,z=2-x$ and a cylinder $x=1-(y-1)^2$ and $0\le y\le 1$: This can be shown by the solid red region below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the graph! And then how can we interchange the variables to another variable? Like for this integral $\int_0^1\int_0^{1-(y-1)^2}\int_0^{2-x}f(x,y,z)dzdxdy$ ,how can I change to $\iiint f(x,y,z)dxdydz$...

Comment: anyone ca help?

Comment: @amWhy:  Thanks for your kind message.  I am OKAY but don't have much time for being here at least for some days ahead. I am doing my third article so sorry if I'm not here much.

Comment: Well good for you (third article!!). I just miss you, that's all! 8-)

Comment: Checking in on April 20, 2014: I hope you are doing well with all your authoring and publishing!! (But we also miss you here! So when things slow down for you (at least comparatively), you will surely be welcomed back!